# Ring Theory. Isomorphism. Write formally.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring. If $a \in R$, show that the map $f(x) \longmapsto f(x + a)$ is a ring isomorphism of $R[X]$.

It is easy to show the homomorphism. I see that the bijection is true intuitively, but I don't know how to write formally. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume you mean $f(x) = x + a$. However, this doesn't send zero to zero, or send one to one, so I don't see how it could even be a ring homomorphism.

Comment: $f(x) \mapsto f(x + a)$ is a ring isomorphism of $R[x]$.

Comment: Yeah! $R[X]$... typing error, sorry

Comment: What's your definition of polynomials? And/or are you familiar with one of their categorical properties? If you know that polynomials are adjoint to the forgetful functor this is immediate, or if you know a universal property of polynomials, this should also be immediate.

Comment: @jgon, this question is from a list of ring theory, I don't yet know categorical properties.

Comment: Oh actually sorry I also misread your question, I thought the issue was showing the homomorphism not the bijection. Joshua gave you a great answer there

Comment: You seem to have confused the title field with the tags field. And you also added a random imperative demand. This makes for a really obnoxious and useless title. Please try to write a more descriptive one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can write down the inverse function $R[x] \to R[x]$, $f(x) \mapsto f(x-a)$. This is a homomorphism because it is the same as $f(x) \mapsto f(x + (-a))$, which said you already showed is a homomorphism.

Comment: Making the composition, which will result in identity, is enough, right?

Comment: You need to check that the composition both ways is the identity, and that implies that it is a bijection.